# How To Compute the Cost of Querying an Additional Table Using LEFT JOIN?

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, join, estimation

I've been tasked with estimating the marginal cost of joining an additional table in reporting queries written in SQL for the PostgreSQL database.  I was given a test program to test the performance of the query.  There appears to be no statistically significant difference between run times whether or not the joined table is populated.  How can I write a better test to illustrate the difference in query times between the two scenarios?

In each case, the SQL is the same, joining table A with table B.  The only difference is whether or not table B contains any data.

Table A has these columns:

```
    Column    |            Type             
--------------+-----------------------------
 sid          | bigint                      
 cluster      | text                         
 sn           | text                        
 tag_id       | integer                      
 src_ip       | text                         
 dst_ip       | text                         
 dst_port     | integer                      
 protocol     | text                         
 src_intf     | text                         
 dst_intf     | text                         
 disp         | smallint                     
 rcvd_bytes   | bigint                       
 sent_bytes   | bigint                       
 duration     | integer                      
 count        | integer                      
 start_time   | timestamp without time zone  
 policy_id    | text                         
 src_user     | text                         
 dst_domain   | text                         
 app_id       | text                         
 signature_id | text                         
 deny_type_id | text                         
 reputation   | text                         
 wb_cat_id    | text                         
 alarm_name   | text                         
 virus        | text                         
 sender       | text                         
 recipients   | text                         
 host         | text                         
 dlp_rule_id  | text                         
 spam_type    | text                         
 spam_action  | text
```

Table B has these columns:

```
    Column    |            Type             
--------------+-----------------------------
 appliance_id | integer                      
 ip           | inet                         
 fqdn         | text                         
 resolve_time | timestamp without time zone  
 expire_time  | timestamp without time zone
```

The two tables are joined by an IPv4 address of type *inet*.

Test data populates tables A and B with just over 500 rows of data each.

With table B populated, on average, the test program that runs query takes 18.216 seconds of total time to run.  The standard deviation between runs is 1.143 seconds.

With table B empty, on average, the test program that runs query takes 18.523 seconds of total time to run.  The standard deviation between runs is 1.928 seconds.

The sample size in each case is six runs.  I suspect I'll need to use a much larger sample size, but am not certain what an appropriate sample size would be.

Comment: There's no *inet* column in the first table, how is it joined then? And 18 seconds to join 500 rows each is quite slow, there must be something more complicated going on. Is there any possibility in PostgreSQL to get the actual CPU/IO usage for those queries and include them in the comparison, too?

Comment: Table A is older, **should** have used inet, but used text for the  IP address.  The report test program first populates table A with a known set of data, then runs the report.  I will probably need to remove some of code from the test program, if it turns out the code is not useful, not contributing to the goal of measuring query execution time.

Comment: If the tables are that small (500 rows) then with the proper types (joining type inet to type text is a showstopper ...) and the correct table structure, a query like this should complete within 10 ms or so.

Comment: I was using an integration test to run the queries but have since switched to a hand-crafted SQL query passed to psql by a shell script.  I've generated additional data, increasing the size of table A sixfold to about 3000 rows.  Table B remains at 500 rows.  I'm seeing more reasonable results: an average of 23.586 seconds with Table B populated and 19.431 seconds with Table B empty (21% overhead).  I made 10 runs of 100 iterations each, both with and without Table B populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a simple query using a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT * FROM a
         LEFT JOIN b
                   ON a.src_ip::inet = b.ip
                   AND b.resolve_time IS NOT NULL AND b.resolve_time <= now()
                   AND b.expire_time IS NOT NULL AND now() < b.expire_time
```

I then ran 10 tests of 100 iterations (queries) each and timed the results of each test run.

Here are the results:

[image: Query Run Times]

By averaging the run times and computing the ratio of the run time with Table B populated to the run time without Table B populated, I was able to compute an overhead of 21.38% for the query with Table B over the query without.